# Changing nginx default log format sometimes doesn't work

Tags: nginx, web-server, logging

I've recently set up fail2ban to work with my custom nginx logging format (called "main"), I have all my sites logging to a different *.access.log file. I still had to change the default format in ^access.log so I added another server{} block to my nginx configuration which looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    ...

    access_log logs/access.log main;
    error_log logs/error.log;
}
```

Everything seems to be working as expected, but sometimes I can still see the default logging format in the ^access.log file. I used grep to filter all of them and it seems like they all get the 301 status code, I do have a custom script on all my sites which is:

```
# check if connecting to http
if ($scheme = "http") {
    # if yes, set $temp_cache to 1, if no stays at undefined
    set $temp_cache 1;
}
# check if address is website.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/*
if ($request_uri ~ ^/.well-known/acme-challenge/(.+)$) {
    # if yes, set $temp_cache to 11, if no stays at 1
    set $temp_cache 2$temp_cache;
}
# check if $temp_cache is 1
if ($temp_cache = 1) {
    # if yes, change http to https
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

I think this might be the cause, as there are no other configuration lines that redirect the user with 301.
Any help is appreciated!